How to automate the process of ADB2C setup in different environments
I have a activity. Need help from you guys. My company is working on Azure cloud and they have ADB2C service running in the cloud which is setup manually for different environments. They need a plan to know how can we automate the process of configuring ADB2C for different environment. Please help if possible
I am doing R&D and got few option but not sure about them

This question is similar to: Azure cli or rest api end to upload custom policy. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Use CI/CD pipelines.
You use placeholders to replace the values e.g. tenantID.
